# Change the background color of a button

Tags: ios, button, background, background-color

I have code that counts upwards when buttons on my app are pressed, but I'd also like to change the button's background color once it has been tapped.

Can I simply add a `backgroundColor` to the below code?

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed {
count++;
totalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hours\n%li",(long)count];
}
@end
```

Comment: For a similar question, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660318/how-to-change-bgcolour-of-button-when-tapped-in-swift/35660770#35660770

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. The easiest thing to do is change your IBAction so it receives the button that's been tapped.

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)button {
   button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

(You'll need to reconnect the outlet from the nib as well so it knows that the new selector is buttonPressed:, not just buttonPressed.